# Size of an object based on a variable

Tags: image, game-maker-studio-2

The code shown below is meant to change the size of a bullet based on a changing variable. But when I put this code in the create tab, the size of the bullet stays the same, regardless of the variable's value.

```
image_xscale = global.Pwr;
image_yscale = global.Pwr;
```

Comment: You don't tell us how you use this code, how those variables are being used?

Comment: The `image_*scale` instance variables resize an instance's sprite unless custom drawing code is defined by you in the _Draw Event_. When is this code being called? How are you rendering the object sprite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code in the step of your object, not the create tab.

```
image_xscale = global.Your_variable;
image_yscale = global.Your_variable;
```